# Doctrine result crashs if it includes Datetime

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm

Im working with Symfony2.6, Doctrine and a MySql Database.
And if the result of the following query is not empty Symfony crashes with the Message: "Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string".
The database field timestamp is a datetime.

```
           $query = "SELECT a
                      FROM TestBundle:Test a
                      where a.test = :test
                        and a.timestamp >= :from
                        and a.timestamp <= :to
                       order by a.timestamp";

    $query = $em ->createQuery($query)
        ->setParameter('test', $test)
        ->setParameter('from', $formdata['from'])
        ->setParameter('to', $formdata['to']);

    $result = $query->getResult();
```

Why is symfony trying to Convert the datetime to a string?

Comment: Very strange, you can try forcing the parameters type with `setParameter('from', $formdata['from'],\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type\DATETIME)` Can you post the ORM column definition? the column name timestamp is probably a reserved keyword, how do you have handled this?

Comment: what kind of Doctrine Type is timestamp? is it a \DateTime or a Date? what kind of type does $formdata['from'] deliver?

Comment: I think you can't use `timestamp` as a column name in doctrine. Doctrine doesn't escape column names with \`. If you use SQL query try to wrap your column name with ` \`a.timestamp\` `. But if Im right best solution will be to rename columns.

Comment: The ORM:
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="timestamp", type="datetime")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $timestamp;

The Formdata delivers a Datetime Object  
The Column name timestamp is only a example

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess here because there no enough code for us to justify what could be wrong so I guess this is what you're doing. If not then please provide more code.

**ENTITY**

```
/**
 * @var DateTime
 */
$protected $timestamp;

/**
 * @return DateTime
 */
public function getTimestamp()
{
    return $this->timestamp;
}
```

**WHAT POSSIBLY YOU'RE DOING**

`echo $a->getTimestamp()`

**WHAT YOU SHOULD DO INSTEAD**

`echo $a->getTimestamp()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

**Example**

```
echo 'CREATING A DATETIME STRING FROM A DATETIME OBJECT';
echo '<br />';
$objectDatetime = new DateTime();
$stringDatetime = $objectDatetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $stringDatetime;

echo '<hr />';

echo 'CREATING A DATETIME OBJECT FROM A DATETIME STRING';
echo '<br />';
$objectDatetime2 = new DateTime($stringDatetime);
$stringDatetime2 = $objectDatetime2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $stringDatetime2;
```

---

**UPDATE**

I would also do something like below. Open for improvements though, just giving you an idea.

```
->setParameter('from', (trim($formdata['from'])) ? new \DateTime($formdata['from']) : null)
```

Comment: I didn't use the timesamp anywhere. There happens nothing after           
$result = $query->getResult();

Comment: Try this: `->setParameter('from', new \DateTime($formdata['from']))` and `->setParameter('to', new \DateTime($formdata['to']))`. Only if there is actually data in them so you need to check if `$formdata['from']` and `$formdata['to']` are empty or not.

Comment: That doesn't help. ... It only crashes of the database returns a result. So it must be a Problem with the result and not the SQL method.

Comment: Right before processing `$result` array (in your controller, service where ever you're calling it to process), put an `exit('hello');` and see what happens. If you see `hello` message then anything comes after that (your code) has the problem.

Comment: If I put it before the getResult I see the "hello" if i put it after the getResult the error shows